# How to create Password protected excel in Java?

Tags: java, excel, passwords

In java i need to create a password protected excel without any third party jars.

Without any third party api we can create excel file in java. Because xls document is similar to html document and xlsx file is a zip file and this zip containd many xml.

For encryption here some information available
http://chicago.sourceforge.net/devel/docs/excel/encrypt.html

But i dont know how to implement this encryption. How can i do ?

Comment: Add context. What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you willing to use a jar designed for working with excel spreadsheets?

Comment: "without any third party jars" - I interpret this to mean "no, I'm not willing."  What's your view?

Comment: How are you creating EXCEL files on the first place without any third party jars?

Comment: I need to create password protected excel file in java with  or without external jar. I tried POI, JExcelAPi. This apis have no option for password protection. Is any other api available ?

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to create an Excel document without 3rd party `JARs`.

This is because Excel is owned & copyrighted to Microsoft(R).  They do have APIs available, and people have applied this to Java, one being [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

JExcelApi doesn't support password protection however.  For that, I only know of commercially available products, such as [Aspose.Total for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.total-for-java/default.aspx).  However, bear in mind it's easy with Java to get around the password protection: [(see here)](http://k2java.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/reading-password-protected-excel-file.html).  Might be worth rethinking how you're doing password protection :)

**Answer summary:** Java itself doesn't have a built in way to manipulate Excel; you'll need to use an external library.

Comment: I tried JExcelApi. But for password protection their is no option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need Free api. :)

Comment: Wish I could then with that one, but as it stands doesn't look like there is one that I know of.  :(   If you feel this is as solved as it can be, please mark the answer.

Comment: We can create a excel without third party api . I created in java and its working for me. For sample just refer http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/WDJava/Export+to+Excel+%28Without+third+party+APIs%29